# php: sort multidimensional array based on key that can be exist or not

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i need to reorder a multiarray based on key name. But that key is not only the same (there is only 2 type of key names like example). I'll post an example:

```
$array = array(
   0 => array(
      "FixedValue" => 550
   ),
   1 => array(
      "Percentage" => 10
   ),
   2 => array(
      "FixedValue" => 10
   ),
   3 => array(
      "FixedValue" => 980
   ),
   4 => array(
      "Percentage" => 90
   )
)
```

My goal is to have a new array where list of "FixedValue" appears before "Percentage" like:

```
$new_array = array(
   0 => array(
      "FixedValue" => 550
   ),
   1 => array(
      "FixedValue" => 10
   ),
   2 => array(
      "FixedValue" => 980
   ),
   3 => array(
      "Percentage" => 90
   ),
   4 => array(
      "Percentage" => 10
   )
)
```

I don't need value sorting, but only key sorting.

Any suggest?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = array(
  0 => array(
    "FixedValue" => 550
  ),
  1 => array(
    "Percentage" => 10
  ),
  2 => array(
    "FixedValue" => 10
  ),
  3 => array(
    "FixedValue" => 980
  ),
  4 => array(
    "Percentage" => 90
  )
);

usort($array,function($a,$b) {
  return key($a) <=> key($b);
});

var_dump($array);
```

Results:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["FixedValue"]=>
    int(550)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["FixedValue"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["FixedValue"]=>
    int(980)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Percentage"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Percentage"]=>
    int(90)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function mySort($a, $b) {
    $a = key($a);
    $b = key($b);
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
$newArray = $array;
usort($newArray, 'mySort');
```